# Why not passing "this" instead of using document.getElementById() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I started learn JavaScript and in some tutorials I saw that was used document.getElementById() and in some tutorials in same case was used "this" that was passed from control that fired the event. 
Maybe someone can explain why should I prefer one way over an other?
Thank's a lot

Comment: you only need to "pass this" from inline event attributes, otherwise the function knows what _this_ means...

Answer (score 1):

Functions assigned as Events have their `this` context as the Object to which the Event belongs. In other words, the Element itself.

```
// you can get Element a number of ways including document.getElementById('idHere')
function someFunc(){
  this.style.color = 'blue';
}
Element.onclick = someFunc;
```

or

```
Element.addEventListener('click', someFunc);
```

or

```
Element.onclick = function(){
  this.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

or

```
function someFunc(context){
  context.style.color = 'blue';
}
Element.onclick = function(){
  someFunc(this);
  // more code here
  // could use document.getElementById('whatever') to get HTML Element with id='whatever'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the documentation from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) MDN page on `addEventListener`? Make sure you look at the section on [the value of `this` within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler). The earlier examples use `document.getElementById` to look up an arbitrary element. For example, you could attach a click handler to a button (or any other element), that modifies some *other* element when it is clicked. In this case, you don't really do anything with the object that generated the click event. So in the handler, you will use `document.getElementById` to modify the element you want.

However, in some other cases you would like to modify the element itself. For example, you might want to change the color of an element the user clicks on, to let them know that its state has changed (a toggle basically). In this case, you want access to the element that actually generated the event, and you can do that by using `this`. Here `this` means "I am the HTML element who generated this event".

In a more general context, `this` can have different meanings, and it depends on the use case. In the context of event handlers, `this` means the element that generated the event. In other cases, such as in object-oriented JavaScript, `this` in a function can refer to the parent object of that function. JavaScript is flexible enough that a function can have whatever `this` value the author decides. In well-written code, `this` has a meaning that generally makes sense, and usually refers to some sort of "owning" context or object.